# Create a workItem after build fails with @Current on IterationPath

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to trigger a workItem Creation after build failure.
I wanted to create a workItem under the using the macro `@currentIteration` but sounds like I don't know the correct syntax.

I can see on my build summary the error:

> Failed to create work item for build failure: TF401347: Invalid tree name given for work item -1, field 'System.IterationPath'.

So far I've used:

`System.IterationPath = @currentIteration`

`System.IterationPath = @CurrentIteration('[projectName]\TeamName')`

`System.IterationPath = [projectName]\TeamName@CurrentIteration`

And none of those worked.
Documentation is also not clear.
Can someone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Create a workItem after build fails with @Current on IterationPath

I am afraid you could not use the `@CurrentIteration` macro in the Build Pipeline with azure devops. That because this macro is supported for **Azure Boards** and TFS 2015 and later versions.

You can get the detailed info from the official document [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=vsts):

> Note
>
> Feature availability: The @CurrentIteration macro is supported for
> Azure Boards and TFS 2015 and later versions. The @CurrentIteration
> +/- n macro is supported for Azure Boards and Azure DevOps Server 2019 and later versions. These macros only work when run them from the web
> portal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is a shame. If WIT are not set to the correct iteration it probably wont be seen by development team. Can we use templates to create the WIT?

Comment: @LeandroSantos, I understand how frustrating this is for you. You can submit a user voice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) , when there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously. At this moment, we have to give it actual Iteration Path instead of variable. Besides, we could use template to create the WIT, document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=vsts&tabs=browser. Have a nice day!